# Downsizing amount of code in Django Views and Forms

Tags: python, django

I recently took the Net Ninja Django course and decided to do a little project to as a self learning excerise, I'm trying to create a web app that takes 'meter readings' for different systems (1 - 10).

It doesn't feel like it makes sense to create a function for each System in my Views file and again to create a form for each one in my Forms file, but I can't seem to think of any other way to do it.

This is the Views function, my logic is you would pass the model class to the view function, which calls the form function with the passed model class.

```
def fuelLogSystemOne(request, x):
entries = FuelLogSystemOne.objects.all().order_by('date')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.AddFuelLogOne(request.POST, x)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.staff = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = forms.AddFuelLogOne()
return render(request,'systems/fuellogsystemone.html',{'form':form,'entry':entries})
```

in my forms file:

```
class AddFuelLogOne(forms.ModelForm,x):
class Meta():
    model = models.x
    fields = ['BucketsAdded']
```

My logic is you would then pass the model you needed when calling the fuelsystemLogOne()

But when I make migrations I get an error saying x wasn't defined.

Comment: Why do you subclass on `x`? Normally it should be `class AddFuelLogOne(forms.ModelForm)`, not with an `,x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally do *not* subclass your model into a form. So you should remove the `x` in `` `class AddFuelLogOne(forms.ModelForm,x) ``:

```
class AddFuelLogOne(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.x
        fields = ['BucketsAdded']
```

In your view, you can pass the model instance through the `instance=…` paramete. You can however not retrieve a model object as parameter, but likely an `id`, hence you should perform a lookup:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def fuelLogSystemOne(request, x_id):
    x = get_object_or_404(X, pk=x_id)
    entries = FuelLogSystemOne.objects.all().order_by('date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AddFuelLogOne(request.POST, instance=x)
        if form.is_valid():
            for.instance.staff = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = forms.AddFuelLogOne()
    return render(request,'systems/fuellogsystemone.html',{'form':form,'entry':entries})
```

Extra remarks:

1. It might be a good idea to add a `Form` suffix to your `AddFuelLogOne` class, so `AddFuelLogOneForm`;
2. Normally a model is written in *PerlCase*, so `X`, not `x`;
3. You can drop the `()` in the `class Meta`;
4. A field name and view function is written in `snake_case`, so `fuel_log_system_one` and `buckets_added`.

Comment: This made sense and solved the problem, I appreciate the tips as well.